# select tabbar item programmatically and show the indicator image

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am using UITabBar, not UITabBarController. Whenever user clicks on any tab, I am able to see the underlined image.

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = getImageWithColorPosition(color: UIColor.darkGray, size: CGSize(width:presenterView.frame.size.width/2, height:49), lineSize: CGSize(width:presenterView.frame.size.width/2, height:2))
}
```

//getImageWithColorPosition is for adding underlined image below UITabBarItem

```
func getImageWithColorPosition(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    let rectLine = CGRect(x: 0, y: size.height-lineSize.height, width: lineSize.width, height: lineSize.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rectLine)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    openItem1()
}

public func  tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if (item.tag == 0) {
        openItem1()
    } else {
        openItem2()
    }
}
```

However, when user clicks on any of the tab items then only underlined image is displayed. I want to select a default tab when user lands on the screen for the first time. As I am doing it programmatically, the underline image doesn't show up. I read couple of stack overflow posts which say that selection on UITabBar can not be triggered programmatically.

Is there any other way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to programmatically select a tab on your `UITabBar`, when the user opens the app. You can do this inside the `AppDelegate`, for example in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

In my project I jump to tabs in my tabbar controller depending on events like certain notifications. Inside the `AppDelegate` I use the following code to programmatically select a tab:

```
if let tabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    tabbarController.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Per default the selected item will be the one with index 0 if the app was launched from a cold start and the last opened tab, if the app was in was previously launched and is held in the app switcher.

Hope this is what you are looking for.